# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get this error even though my file has only two columns and I used them.

This is my code:

```
f_in = open('State_Deaths.csv', 'rt')
state_deaths = []
for line in f_in:
    line = line.strip()
    print(line)
    state, deaths = line.split(',')
    state_deaths += state, deaths
print(state_deaths)
```

This is a part of the file :

```
state, deaths
Wyoming,155
Mississippi,641
Arkansas,563
Montana,189
Alabama,862
Oklahoma,668
Kentucky,760
South Carolina,810
South Dakota,140
West Virginia,315
```

Comment: Could you show us a part of your file ?

Comment: @HamzaAbbad I just added it

Comment: @SalehAlswiti Sure you don't have any lines with more than one comma in it?

Comment: Are you intending `state_deaths` to be a list of two-element tuples such as `[(state1,deaths1), (state2,deaths2)]`, or a flat list such as `[state1,deaths1,state2,deaths2]`?

Comment: @jDo So should I edit the file ?

Comment: @JohnGordon  list of two-element

Comment: You can call `line.split(',', 1)` to only split on the first comma instead of every comma.

Comment: If you want a list of two-element tuples, use `state_deaths.append((state,deaths))` instead of `+=`.

Comment: It's probably this line that's causing it `state_deaths += state, deaths`

Comment: @JohnGordon I did it but it before and it gave me this error  append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: You have to enclose `state,deaths` inside TWO levels of parentheses, as I wrote.

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're after a list of lists or a list of tuples, so here's both with some extra input checks that you might not need.

```
state_deaths_lists = []
state_deaths_tuples = []

with open('State_Deaths.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if "," not in line:
            print("Error - No comma found")
        else:
            row_vals = line.split(",")
            if len(row_vals) != 2:
                print("Error - More than 2 elements in line/row")
            else:
                # all's in order
                state_deaths_lists.append(row_vals)
                state_deaths_tuples.append(tuple(row_vals))
```

If your input is nicely formatted and you want a list of list, just use this:

```
state_deaths = []

with open('State_Deaths.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        row_vals = line.split(",")
        state_deaths.append(row_vals)
```

Comment: +1 for using the list append method instead of +=. Although valid, that is just confusing for anything but a simple counter.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It's odd that python even allows the use of `+=` for lists. It also works for adding strings/characters to other strings but that's also bad practice and should be replaced by `"".join()`. Too flexible for its own good, the snake is :P

Comment: Oh wow. It took me way too long to get that. Hahaha. ``python == snake`` (but ``Python is not snake``!)